# subversion folder rights lost after branching/tagging?

Tags: svn, access-rights

i am using path-based access control in subversion.

My repositories have this structure:

```
/tags
/tags/...
/branches
/branches/...
/trunk/sourcecode
/trunk/documentation
/trunk/internal_information
```

in the folder "internal_information" I want to store internal data which should not be seen by other users than me (username martin).

```
[rep:/]
@users=rw

[rep:/trunk/internal_information]
*=
martin=rw
```

This works great, the folder internal_information is only visible and accessible by me.

However, after creating a branch or tag by me, other users can check out the newly created branch and see the folder "internal_information", as the above declared access rights only apply to the trunk folder.

Is there a way that the permissions are also transfered to the branch/tag?
Or is there a way that I can globally specifify that any folders named e.g. "internal information" are only accessible my me?

Thanks and best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Subversion's built-in path-based authorization only allows for control on explicitly-defined paths - no wildcards, no "heuristics"-based rules. The most-specific rule "wins".

To go beyond this, you'll need to look for external tools (not sure if there are any that do this) or *possibly* Apache configuration to block access before the request hits svn itself. If you needed to only lock down write access, a pre-commit hook would do the job - but those aren't an option with reads.